# How can I use GTK4 of C to get the pixels of the screen?

Tags: c, linux, gtk, x11

How can I use GTK4 of C to get the pixels of the screen?

If GTK4 does not have an API, how can I get the pixels of the screen from Xlib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about GTK4 but in X11:

- [XGetImage](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/graphics/XGetImage.html)
- [XGetWindowAttributes](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XGetWindowAttributes.html)

**Example**:

```
//open display and get the root window of the default screen
//note: there could be more than one screen
Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
Window root = RootWindow(dpy, DefaultScreen(dpy));

//get the window attributes of the root window
XWindowAttributes attr;
XGetWindowAttributes(dpy, root, &attr);

//get the image of the root window
XImage* image = XGetImage(
    dpy, 
    root, 
    0, 0, //attr.x, attr.y
    attr.width, attr.height, 
    AllPlanes, 
    ZPixmap
);
```

**Hint**: Include `X11/Xlib.h` and compile with `-lX11`